# How to create a persistant Dialogue Box in android app

Tags: android, dialog

I am using this code, to create a dialogue box in my android app.
The popup dialogue box is created successfully but the problem is that if i touch anywhere on the screen, the dialogue box disappears. I want the Dialogue box to remain persistent on the screen, even if the user touches any other part of the screen. The user should be allowed to only choose either the positive or negative response on the dialogue box and only then proceed.

Can someone please tell me how I can modify my code to achieve that.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder1.setMessage("Would you click to proceed with this app.");
builder1.setCancelable(true);

builder1.setPositiveButton(
    "Yes",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

builder1.setNegativeButton(
    "No",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
alert11.show();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting this behaviour with:

```
builder1.setCancelable(true);
```

change it to false & you are fine.

```
builder1.setCancelable(false);
```